# Drupal 8 Class 'Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface' not found

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I am trying to write a custom php script in my Drupal site root that checks if the user is logged in. To check this I import bootstrap.inc. However when I do this it throws me this error
[image]

This is the code of the php script in my site root:

```
<?php
require_once './core/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
global $user;
var_dump($user->uid);
?>
```

Anyone has a solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by using a complete different approach. I wrote a module which sets a cookie on the moment that the user logs in to drupal (I use the hook_user_login for this). When the user logs out I delete that cookie (I use the hook_user_logout for this). This is the code of my test.module:

```
/**
* @param $account
*/
function intersoc_content_user_login($account)
{
  setcookie("user", "loggedin", time() + (86400 * 30),"/"); 
}
/**
* @param $account
*/
function intersoc_content_user_logout($account)
{
  if (isset($_COOKIE['user']))
  {
    unset($_COOKIE['user']);
    setcookie('user', '', time() - 3600, '/'); //Clearing cookie
  }
}
```

Then in my custom script in the site root I check if the cookie is set. When the cookie exists => The user is logged in. If the cookie doesn't exist then the user isn't logged in. The isLoggedIn() function below:

```
/**
 * @return bool which indicates if the user is logged in or not
 */
private function isLoggedIn()
{
    if(isset($_COOKIE["user"]))
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

It isn't the most beautiful solution, but it works!!!

Answer (score 1):

To bootstrap Drupal 8, you need different code. Drupal 8 doesn't have any [`drupal_bootstrap()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_bootstrap/7.x) function, so the code you are using would throw a PHP error.

You can use [authorize.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21authorize.php/8.6.x) as guideline to write your own script.

```
use Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpExceptionInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

$autoloader = (require_once 'autoload.php');

try {
  $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
  $kernel = DrupalKernel::createFromRequest($request, $autoloader, 'prod');
  $kernel->prepareLegacyRequest($request);
} catch (HttpExceptionInterface $e) {
  $response = new Response('', $e->getStatusCode());
  $response
    ->prepare($request)
    ->send();
  exit;
}

\Drupal::moduleHandler()
  ->addModule('system', 'core/modules/system');
\Drupal::moduleHandler()
  ->addModule('user', 'core/modules/user');
\Drupal::moduleHandler()
  ->load('system');
\Drupal::moduleHandler()
  ->load('user');

$account = \Drupal::service('authentication')
  ->authenticate($request);
if ($account) {
  \Drupal::currentUser()
    ->setAccount($account);
  if (\Drupal::currentUser()->isAuthenticated() {
    // The user is logged-in.
  }
}
```

Comment: Tnx Man, you are a true life saver!